# Read a text file with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following problem: I want to read a txt file with JQuery and put it in a div, but I have not found anyway to do this and solve my question. I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(getImages);
function getImages() {
    $.getJSON("/home/ListImagesProducts", showImages);
}

function showImages(data) {
    $("#directoryImages").append("<ul id = 'productImages'>");
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var directories = data[i];
        $("#directoryImages ul").append("<li><img src='../Content/images/Products/" + directories.ImageName + "' /><add value='" + directories.DescriptionName + "'</li>");
    }
    //$("#directoryImages").append("</ ul>");
}
</script>
```

From < add ...> I want to include the file, but it is not working. The method that include the values to this function is this, in my Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ListImagesProducts() {
     List < string > tempImages = new List < string > ();
     List < string > tempDescription = new List < string > ();

     Directory directory;
     //Marca o diretório a ser listado
     DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\Lucas B\Tutoriais\Programação\Programas de Teste\ThreeJay\ThreeJay\Content\images\Products");
     //Executa função GetFile(Lista os arquivos desejados de acordo com o parametro)
     FileInfo[] Images = diretorio.GetFiles("*.jpg");
     FileInfo[] Description = diretorio.GetFiles("*.txt");

     List < Directory > model = new List < Directory > ();

     foreach(FileInfo fileinfo in Images) {
         tempImages.Add(fileinfo.Name);
     }

     foreach(FileInfo fileinfo in Description) {
         tempDescription.Add(fileinfo.Name);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < tempImages.Count; i++) {
         directory = new Directory();
         directory.ImageName = tempImages.ElementAt(i);
         directory.DescriptionName = tempDescription.ElementAt(i);

         model.Insert(i, directory);
     }

     var ficheiro = model;

     return Json(ficheiro, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

But I would like to read the text file through JQuery. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you missing the closing brace for 'add' in your code? `<add value='" + directories.DescriptionName + "'</li>"`

Comment: Yes, I already saw this. But it is not working yet.

Comment: do you get any error(s)...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't follow your code but if you want to read a text file with JQuery ,you can use .load method

```
 $(function () {
     $('#elementID').load('sample.txt');
 });
```

It won't work on local with chrome because of file:// access problem .Check it with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'text`' datatype in your `$.get()` request.

```
$.get('file_to_read.txt', function(data) {
     $(element).text(data);
}, 'text');
```

or you can use `ajax`  load function call in jQuery

```
$("element").load("'file_to_read.txt");
```